# Dynamic styling using a method angular 4

Tags: css, angular, sanitization

i am building a tree structure in angular 4. my issue is i have to start each node at the same level and indent only the name text from the left border.
for every node i have got the depth of the node. i want to add a style like this.

```
<p   style="padding-left : calc_padding(depth)"> some Text </p>

calc_padding(depth){
return depth *5
}
```

how can i do that.

i have read style sanitizer but could not find how to use it in my case.

i have tried to impliment `[style] = "method(depth)"`
and `[style.padding-left] = "method(depth)"` but i am unable to get the things done as i have wanted.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the style binding like this:

```
<p [style.paddingLeft.px]="calc_padding(depth)"></p>
```

If the value returned from `calc_padding` should be interpreted as pixels